# Native base dynamically show success or Error input

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I want to have two simple input boxes.

There is a loginName input box, and a password input box.

Currently I map the value of these two input box into a "state".

Now, using NativeBase. How do I dynamically show "success" "error" like how they did in the demo? 
http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.5.9/components#successInputTextbox

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Passing a prop `success` is equivalent to passing `success={true}`

So if you have state variables like inputSuccess and inputError, you can do this:

```
<InputGroup 
  iconRight 
  success={this.state.inputSuccess ? true : false} 
  error={this.state.inputError ? true : false}>
  <Icon name='ios-checkmark-circle' style={{color:'#00C497'}}/>
  <Input placeholder='Textbox'/>
</InputGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I tried but it's not working. can you please explain little more ?

Comment: @DineshSpartacus The above code should work for native-base 0.5.x. The API has changed, especially after 2.x.x. You have to change your code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The Native Base documentation (version 2.12) has [this example](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#error-textbox-headref):

```
state = { error: 'Some error' };
// ...
<Content>
  <Item error={this.state.error !== ''}>
    <Input 
      placeholder='Textbox with Error Input'
      error={'#d50000'}
    />
    <Icon name='close-circle' />
  </Item>
</Content>
```

The error prop inside `<Input />` is to set the error color. The invalid state is set at the item error prop.

Answer (score 0):

Base don Himanshu answer.
There is no need to set false, that's the default value for success and error.
Additionally, you can also can also use conditions to change de icon!

```
<InputGroup 
  iconRight 
  success={this.state.inputSuccess} 
  error={this.state.inputError}>
  <Icon name={this.state.inputSuccess ? 'checkmark-circle' : 'close-circle'}/>
  <Input placeholder='Textbox'/>
</InputGroup>
```